# SharePoint 2013 Global Navigation

Tags: 2013, navigation, enterprise

Is managed metadata global navigation (pinning terms) in SharePoint 2013 a enterprise feature?  Does it require an enterprise license?

Answer (score 1):

Managed metadata feature exists in SharePoint 2013 Server Standard and Enterprise. Foundation does not have this feature. So enterprise or standard license is required.

[COMPARE SHAREPOINT FOUNDATION 2013 VS. SERVER 2013](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-foundation-server/)

[image]